# Oracle - some problems with Group Operations

Tags: oracle, select, grouping

I need your help ... i tryed more time but can't find a soluction (i think that is simple but I have errors in oracle :( :( )

an example: 
i have a table with 
teams: what team played 
gameDate: when played
goalHours: when teamA or teamB do a goal
goalNumber: how much goal are doing in the same hour
endGame: when finish the game

```
teams            gameDate goalHours goalNumber endGame  
team01-VS-team02 20110901 21 2 20110902
team01-VS-team02 20110901 22 1 20110902
team01-VS-team02 20110901 23 3 20110902
team03-VS-team02 20110902 18 3 20110905 
team03-VS-team02 20110902 19 1 20110905
team04-VS-team02 20110904 06 5 20110906
team01-VS-team02 20110101 18 1 20110902
```

I need a select with all distinct teamA-VS-teamB  the last gameDate 
i need for every distinct teamA-VS-teamB, in their last game, the distinct hours of goalHours,  the sum of goalNumber, and when stop the game.

something like this:

```
teams            lastGameDate distinctGoalHours sumGoalNumber endGame  
team01-VS-team02 20110901 3 6 20110902
team03-VS-team02 20110902 2 4 20110905 
team04-VS-team02 20110904 1 5 20110906
```

i try with:

```
SELECT   teams,
MAX(gameDate),
MAX (endDate),
SUM (goalNumber),
COUNT (DISTINCT goalHours)
       FROM myTable
GROUP BY teams
```

this select doesn't work well because i don't want count 
team01-VS-team02 20110101 18 1 20110902, this isn't last game date. 
with this select i have 4 distinctGoalHours  and  7 sumGoalNumber.

i need a select with

```
team01-VS-team02 20110901 3 6 20110902
team03-VS-team02 20110902 2 4 20110905
team04-VS-team02 20110904 1 5 20110906
```

... I hope that i show you all information that you need and thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 1):

Like any other SQL, you need to restrict the result set with the appropriate filter.  In your case, you need to use a sub-query to identify the latest `gameDate` for each team.

There are several different ways of implementing this.  Here is one which works:

```
SQL> SELECT   teams,
            MAX(gameDate),
            MAX (endGame),
            SUM (goalNumber),
            COUNT (DISTINCT goalHours)
FROM  myTable
WHERE (teams, gameDate) IN
    ( select teams, max(gameDate)
      from myTable
      GROUP BY teams )
GROUP BY teams
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12  
TEAMS                          MAX(GAMED MAX(ENDGA SUM(GOALNUMBER) COUNT(DISTINCTGOALHOURS)
------------------------------ --------- --------- --------------- ------------------------
team03-VS-team02               02-SEP-11 05-SEP-11               4                        2
team01-VS-team02               01-SEP-11 02-SEP-11               6                        3
team04-VS-team02               04-SEP-11 06-SEP-11               5                        1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank You!!! :D :D ... (teams, gameDate) IN
    ( select teams, max(gameDate), i like this solution!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the gameDate in the group by. Something like:

```
SELECT  teams
    ,   gameDate
    ,   MAX( endDate )
    ,   SUM( goalNumber )
    ,   COUNT( DISTINCT goalHours )
FROM    myTable
GROUP BY teams
    ,    gameDate
```